# 'Changed' in 'She is changed' - an adjective or a verb?

Tags: parts-of-speech

From Dickens's *Hard Times*, ch. 13:

> ‘Thou art an Angel. Bless thee, bless thee!’
>
> ‘I am, as I have told thee, Stephen, thy poor friend. Angels are not like me. Between them, and a working woman fu’ of faults, there is a deep gulf set. My little sister is among them, but she is **changed**.’

Is *changed* here a verb or an adjective?

*Change* here means *death*: an antique sense for the word, mentioned in [The Century Dictionary](http://www.global-language.com/CENTURY/). A quote from there:

> All the days of my appointed time will I wait, till my *change* come.

Comment: looks *adjective* to me in the context of the previous sentence. You are among people but then you *adjective - changed*.

Answer (score 1):

Adjective. The tense change alone should give you a clue - if it was a verb it would be *is changing*.

Answer (score 0):

It's an adjective, since it describes the person.

To understand this easily, frame your sentence as:

> "She is a changed person"

and you can derive your answer.

Comment: Except it would be 'she is _a_ changed person'